# How to merge IOS push notification in Android push notification use web service

Tags: android, ios

I am using push notification in android push notification like GCM and i want to add IOS push notification in GCM.
Admin will set text in text box and than notification will be sent to both device like android and IOS devices.

Thanks

Comment: [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gcm for android & apns for IOS seperately or use 3rd lib such as https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications.

In 1st solution, when phone connects to your web server. Web server must recognize client is android or ios. And later when web server wants to send message to client it will send push notification to GCM or APNS.